# Website showing old versions - Git or Laravel?

Tags: git, laravel, version-control, routes, view

I've been attempting to move a website's filesystem to a new server, and I'm running into an issue I'm completely baffled by. When I view the filesystem through the server, FTP client, and ssh, I can see all the files are up to date and match what I have on my most recent development version. But when I try and access it through a page, I see a version of the front page that is months old and *doesn't even exist* in the filesystem anymore.

The only thing I could think of that could be causing this behavior is Git, but the server doesn't even have it installed. My .git repository in the filesystem got moved along with the file transfer - but can a git repository go so far as to superimpose old versions of a filesystem over existing files without git even being installed or instantiated?

What I'm using

- Laravel
- Ubuntu Server
- Git on my development server (not installed on production)
- Filezilla for uploads

When I check my routes with Artisan, everything checks out, and I can't access any of the old version's routes that I've since deleted - it just shows a 404. I think it's just the views directory that's being superimposed with these old files. But I don't know what's causing it or how to stop it.

Comment: Do you use any sort of caching for this website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might have old versions of cache files for your views, and no permission to rewrite new files.

Try clearing out your /app/storage/views folder, and making sure that it's writable by the user running your web server.

Comment: Ok, that worked! At least partially. Unfortunately, I'm still unable to get any of my routes running - I can see the right version of the homepage but nothing is functional. Any advice?

Comment: If you're using route caching, the problem might be the same as with the views. Try running `php artisan route:clear`.